# video file issue - unable to extract or open file on mac os x

Tags: macos, mac, vlc-media-player, quicktime, macos-highsierra

I decided to download one movie from torrent and the description says

```
Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : Main@L4
Format settings                          : CABAC / 4 Ref Frames
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, Reference frames        : 4 frames
Codec ID                                 : V_MPEG4/ISO/AVC
Duration                                 : 2 h 13 min
Nominal bit rate                         : 1 951 kb/s
Width                                    : 1 920 pixels
Height                                   : 1 080 pixels

Audio
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : AAC LC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec Low Complexity
Codec ID                                 : A_AAC-2
Duration                                 : 2 h 13 min
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel layout                           : L R
Sampling rate                            : 44.1 kHz
Frame rate                               : 43.066 FPS (1024 SPF)
Compression mode                         : Lossy
```

The filename is like `1080p.BluRay.x264.AAC5.1-[YTS-MX].Subtitles.Bitrate.7300KB.Samplerate.48.0kHz.exe` , i ve `vlc` and `quicktime player` installed but it is not opening , mac os 10.13.1 , it is trying to unarchive but no app is able to do so and i am unable to watch the movie , can u suggest me what to do ?

Comment: It's probably a viral load. Think yourself luck it won't run on a Mac.

Comment: @Tetsujin r u sure cause it has many seeds

Comment: Who posts a pirate movie as an exe? People who want to screw your computer.

Comment: @Tetsujin , thanks a lot man , i watched the movie on telegram , process was hassle free and safer than torrent